# I am working as a Librarian in your esteemed Institute since 06.10.2012

Tags: grammaticality

Which of the following two sentences is correct?

1. *I am working as a Librarian in your esteemed Institute since 06.10.2012.*
2. *I have been working as a librarian in your esteemed Institute since 06.01.2012.*

Comment: The latter is more correct

Comment: The first one I would understand, but also I would guess the writer's native language is not English.

Comment: _Esteemed_ in that sentence sounds like 19th century hollow flattery. That hasn't changed magically in the 21st.

Answer (score 2):

The first sentence is wrong; the second one is alright, assuming you are still working there.

The first sentence would be fine if it was *until* rather than *since*, as in *I am working here until the end of the month*.

Answer (score 1):

The latter, under the assumption (as another poster stated) that you still work there.

The first sentence is wrong, and you cannot say it. The second sentence, using present perfect continuous implies an action that begun in the past, and has continued up until the moment of your writing.

You could also consider the present perfect simple: 'I have worked as a Librarian in your institute for six years' or something like this.